# NumberFormatException when using aDouble in specs2 scala

Tags: scala, tdd, numberformatexception, specs2

I can not understand why this is happening, lets suppose the code from [Specs 2 GWT clauses](https://github.com/etorreborre/specs2/blob/master/examples/src/test/scala/examples/GWTSpec.scala), which is

```
class GWTSpec extends Specification with GWT with StandardRegexStepParsers { def is = s2"""
 A given-when-then example for a calculator                       ${calculator1.start}
   Given the following number: 1
   And a second number: 2
   And a third number: 6
   When I use this operator: +
   Then I should get: 9
   And it should be >: 0                                          ${calculator1.end}
 Now with the multiplication                                      
"""
  val anOperator = readAs(".*: (.)$").and((s: String) => s)

  val calculator1 =
    Scenario("calculator1")
      .given(anInt)
      .given(anInt)
      .given(anInt)
      .when(anOperator) { case op :: i :: j :: k :: _ => if (op == "+") i+j+k else i*j*k }
      .andThen(anInt)   { case expected :: sum :: _ => sum === expected }
      .andThen(anInt)   { case expected :: sum :: _ => sum must be_>(expected) } 
}
```

That work well, but, what if I want to use a double instead? for example:

```
class GWTSpec extends Specification with GWT with StandardRegexStepParsers { def is = s2"""
 A given-when-then example for a calculator                       ${calculator1.start}
   Given the following number: 1.0
   And a second number: 2.0
   And a third number: 6.0
   When I use this operator: +
   Then I should get: 9.0
   And it should be >: 0.0                                          ${calculator1.end}
"""
  val anOperator = readAs(".*: (.)$").and((s: String) => s)

  val calculator1 =
    Scenario("calculator1")
      .given(aDouble)
      .given(aDouble)
      .given(aDouble)
      .when(anOperator) { case op :: i :: j :: k :: _ => if (op == "+") i+j+k else i*j*k }
      .andThen(aDouble)   { case expected :: sum :: _ => sum === expected }
      .andThen(aDouble)   { case expected :: sum :: _ => sum must be_>(expected) }
}
```

That is giving `NumberFormatException` for each test statement, the output of `sbt testOnly GWTSpec` is:

```
> testOnly GWTSpec
[info] GWTSpec
[info]  A given-when-then example for a calculator                       
[info] 
[info]    Given the following number: 1.0
[error] ! 
[error]  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "And a third number: 6.0" (FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
[error] sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
[error] sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
[info]    And a second number: 2.0
[error] ! 
[error]  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "And a second number: 2.0" (FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
[error] sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
[error] sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
[info]    And a third number: 6.0
[error] ! 
[error]  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Given the following number: 1.0" (FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
[error] sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
[error] sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
[info]    When I use this operator: +
[info] o    o Then I should get: 9.0
[info]    o And it should be >: 0.0                                          
[info] 
[info] Total for specification GWTSpec
[info] Finished in 478 ms
[info] 2 examples, 6 expectations, 0 failure, 3 errors, 3 skipped
[info] 
[error] Error: Total 5, Failed 0, Errors 3, Passed 0, Skipped 2
[error] Error during tests:
[error]     GWTSpec
```

But I do not understand why it works with `Int` and not with `Double`, the `StandarParsers` for `anInt` and `aDouble` are:

```
  private val wholeNumber = """-?\d+"""
  private val decimalNumber = """(\d+(\.\d*)?|\d*\.\d+)"""

  def anInt = groupAs(wholeNumber).and((_: String).trim.toInt)
  def aDouble = groupAs("-?"+decimalNumber).and((_: String).trim.toDouble)
```

In order to work, I have to declare a new `RegExParser`, like this:

```
class GWTSpec extends Specification with GWT with StandardRegexStepParsers { def is = s2"""
 A given-when-then example for a calculator                       ${calculator1.start}
   Given the following number: 1.0
   And a second number: 2
   And a third number: 6
   When I use this operator: +
   Then I should get: 9.0
   And it should be >: 0.0                                          ${calculator1.end}
"""
  val anOperator = readAs(".*: (.)$").and((s: String) => s)
  val myD = readAs(".*: (\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|\\d*\\.\\d+)$").and((s: String) => s.toDouble)

  val calculator1 =
    Scenario("calculator1")
      .given(myD)
      .given(myD)
      .given(myD)
      .when(anOperator) { case op :: i :: j :: k :: _ => if (op == "+") i+j+k else i*j*k }
      .andThen(myD)   { case expected :: sum :: _ => sum === expected }
      .andThen(myD)   { case expected :: sum :: _ => sum must be_>(expected) }
}
```

But why can I use `aDouble` as easy as `anInt`?

It is surely some thing I am missing, but can see why this not work.

Comment: This works fine for me on `3.8.6`.

Comment: I'm using 3.8.6 too. Don't know what is happening